# How can I stop a merge in bitbucket if a build fails?

Tags: bitbucket, cicd

In Bitbucket, After a developers code is PR'd and ready to be merged, I want a build to be made when the developer requests to merge, and for the merge to fail if the build fails. I know I can trigger a build when a pull request is made, and then use the merge checks feature, but the developers code can change during the PR which could introduce build breaking bugs. Builds take quite a while too, so I don't want it to happen every time a developer updates their code.

Is there any solution to this? Perhaps via the Build Pipelines feature?